# How call a member data of the parent class instance from the child | Python

Tags: python, oop

I have the following code where I make an instance of the NeuralNet class and this has a subclass (I think so) for the creation of a Layer class.

```
NN=NeuralNet(input_data,output_data,stop_precision=0.01)
NN.add_layer(20,'relu')
class NeuralNet:
    def __init__(self,input_data,output_data,stop_precision=0.1):
       * bla bla
       * bla bla
       #Member that i want to call from child class
       self.input_data=input_data
    def add_layer(self,number_neurons,activation_function,id_layer=None):
       layer_temp=self.Layer(**mando los parametros**)
       #A través de este método intento acceder
       #With this method i'm trying to call the member input_data
       layer_temp.initialize_data()
    class Layer:
       def __init__(self,number_conexions,number_neurons,activation_function,id_layer):
           * bla bla
           * bla bla
        def initialize_data(self):
           if self.id_layer=='input_layer':
              #Here i try to call it
              self.W=super().NeuralNetwork.input_data
              self.W=NeuralNetwork.input_data
```

Then my question is, can I call "input_data" member data of the NeuralNet class instance without having to send it like a parameter to the functions for the creation of Layer class ? Also I have other question as: if Layer class is into NeuralNet class, is it a subclass? or is it an inheritance ? subclass and inheritance are the same ?

Comment: The `Layer` class **is not a child class of `NeuralNet`**, indeed, that wouldn't make much sense any how.

Comment: "Also i have other asks as: if Layer class is into NeuralNet class, is it a subclase ? or is it a inheritance ?" No, **absolutely not**. I'm not sure why you believed that. A quick look at the documentation or random google search would show you how inheritance works in Python

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga right, but, then what i having if i implement it like that ?

Comment: You've just got one class awkwardly defined inside another class.